# Approximating a weakly convergent sequence "uniformly" by a dense subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, approximation, weak-convergence

For a fixed $p \in (1,\infty)$, consider $L^p(\Omega)$ for a bounded domain $\Omega$ in the Euclidean space and a sequence $\{ f_{n} \} \subset L^p(\Omega)$ converging weakly. That is, for each $g \in L^{p'}(\Omega)$ with $p^{-1} + p'^{-1}=1$, the limit
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}  \int_\Omega f_n g
\end{equation}
exists. In this case, it is well-known that there exists a unique $f \in L^p(\Omega)$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}  \int_\Omega f_n g = \int_\Omega f g
\end{equation}

Moreover, we know that $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, the space of compactly supported smooth functions on $\Omega$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$. ,y question is:

> Can we find a double sequence $\{ \phi_{n,m} \} \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $\phi_{n,m}$ approximates $f_n$ in the weak topology uniformly in $n$?

More specifically, can we find a double sequence $\{  \phi_{n,m} \} \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ such that
\begin{equation}
\Bigl \lvert \int_\Omega (f_n-\phi_{n,m}) g \Bigr \rvert \leq C(m,g) 
\end{equation}
where $C(m,g) \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$ for each $g \in L^p$ and $C(m,g)$ is independent of $n$.

I think this is a quite nontrivial problem. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: You can just choose $\phi_{n,m}$ so that $\lVert f_n-\phi_{n,m}\rVert_p<1/m$ and put $C(m,g)=\lVert g\rVert_{p'}/m$. You don't even need a weak convergence of $(f_n)$.

Comment: @MintChocolate Oh...I thought too much and missed this simple truth...Thank you for your insight.

Comment: @MintChocolate The original question I am stuck at is [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467046/approximating-a-sequence-of-tempered-distributions-uniformly-by-schwartz-funct). Could you perhaps help me with this?